# CTRL-C doesn't work on Java program

Tags: java, unix, shell, copy-paste

I found a weird scenario where if I start a java program and I want to exit gracefully with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it doesn't work/respond, I have to do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on the program and this is not cool, doing  a ps lists the process... Anyone please.

Comment: Are you able to post some code?

Answer (score 5):

Under Unix, command line programs have a lot of control over what happens when you try to interrupt them with `^C`.  The default effect of typing `^C` at a terminal is to make the kernel send the `SIGINT` signal to the foreground process group, and the default behavior of `SIGINT` is to kill the process it's sent to, but both of those things can be changed.

The most likely cause of your problem is that your Java program is intercepting `SIGINT` in order to do some cleanup before exiting, but the signal handler is buggy so the process doesn't ever actually exit.  The second most likely cause is that the program is *ignoring* `SIGINT` altogether.  And the least likely cause is that it's put the terminal into "raw mode" so that `^C` just delivers a byte with value 0x03 to its standard input (if it had done that `^Z` probably wouldn't work either).

If you have access to the source code of your program, you can try to fix the buggy signal handler and/or make it stop ignoring the signal.  Otherwise, you're kinda up a creek.  You can try `^\` (control-backslash), which sends a *different* normally-lethal signal (`SIGQUIT`), but this is not guaranteed to work either, and if it does work, it may leave you with a gigantic "core dump" file to get rid of.

The only 100% for sure way to get rid of a malfunctioning process is to send it signal 9 (`SIGKILL`).  Unlike the other lethal signals, it's impossible to intercept, block, or ignore that one.  There is no control key to send signal 9; you have to suspend the process with `^Z`, or open a new terminal window / ssh session, find the process ID with `ps`, and use the `kill` command.  Always try `kill PID` before `kill -9 PID`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (In my case it was problem :)), my issue was that I launched the app using `javaw` instead of `java`.

`javaw` is running the app without console so the CTRL+C is not working.

Another question about the difference between `javaw` to `java` here - [What is the difference between 'java', 'javaw', and 'javaws'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/what-is-the-difference-between-java-javaw-and-javaws/8194750#8194750)