# What is the difference between 'java', 'javaw', and 'javaws'?

Tags: java, java-web-start, javaw

What is the difference between `java`, `javaw`, and `javaws`?

I have found that on Windows most usage of Java is done using `javaw`.

Comment: That's because Windows has this annoying habit of starting an actual Terminal (which should not even be called a "Terminal"...) in the foreground whenever you start a program with `java -cp ...`. As almost nobody wants that, `javaw` is the choice to make that annoying window disappear.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

See Java tools documentation for:

- [`java` command<sup>1</sup>/`javaw` command<sup>2</sup>](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> 1. The **`java`** tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that class's `main` method.
> 2. The **`javaw`** command is identical to `java`, except that with `javaw` there is no associated console window. Use `javaw` when you ***don't** want a command prompt window to appear.*

- [`javaws` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html), the *"[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) command"*

> The `javaws` command launches Java Web Start, which is the reference implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP). Java Web Start launches Java applications/applets hosted on a network. 
>  
> If a JNLP file is specified, `javaws` will launch the Java application/applet specified in the JNLP file.
> The `javaws` launcher has a set of options that are supported in the current release. However, the options may be removed in a future release.

See also [JDK 9 Release Notes
Deprecated APIs, Features, and Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html):

> **Java Deployment Technologies are deprecated and will be removed in a future release** 
> Java Applet and WebStart functionality, including the Applet API, the Java plug-in, the Java Applet Viewer, JNLP and Java Web Start, including the **`javaws` tool**, are all **deprecated in JDK 9** and will be removed in a future release.

Answer (score 80):

**java:** Java application executor which is associated with a console to display output/errors

**javaw:** (*Java windowed*) application executor not associated with console. So no display of output/errors. It can be used to silently push the output/errors to text files. It is mostly used to launch GUI-based applications.

**javaws:** (*Java web start*) to download and run the distributed web applications. Again, no console is associated.

All are part of JRE and use the same JVM.

Comment: so if I've installed JRE, `javaw` should be in my PATH?  (It isn't)

Comment: @endolith, Java installation on Windows doesn't, in my experience, add anything to the PATH variable. If you've only installed JRE, you'll probably have to add the JRE/bin directory to PATH manually; if you've installed JRE and JDK, you'd add the JDK/bin to PATH instead.

Answer (score 10):

*java.exe* is associated with the console, whereas *javaw.exe* doesn't have any such association. So, when *java.exe* is run, it automatically opens a command prompt window where output and error streams are shown.

Answer (score 7):

From http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.user.aix32.60%2Fuser%2Fjava.html:

> The javaw command is identical to java, except that javaw has no associated console window. Use javaw when you do not want a command prompt window to be displayed. The javaw launcher displays a window with error information if it fails.

And javaws is for Java web start applications, applets, or something like that, I would suspect.

Comment: The link is broken: *"The requested page does not exist or might have moved."*

Answer (score 4):

I have checked that the output redirection works with `javaw`:

```
javaw -cp ... mypath.MyClass ... arguments 1>log.txt 2>err.txt
```

It means, if the Java application prints out anything via System.out or System.err, it is written to those files, as also with using java (without `w`). Especially on starting `java`, the JRE may write starting errors (class not found) on the error output pipe. In this respect, it is essential to know about errors. I suggest to use the console redirection in any case if `javaw` is invoked.

In opposite if you use

```
start java .... 1>log.txt 2>err.txt
```

With the Windows console [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command, the console output redirection does *not* work with `java` nor with `javaw`.

Explanation  why it is so: I think that `javaw` opens an internal process in the OS (adequate using the java.lang.Process class), and transfers a known output redirection to this process. If no redirection is given on the command line, nothing is redirected and the internal started process for `javaw` doesn't have any console outputs. The behavior for java.lang.Process is similar. The virtual machine may use this internal feature for `javaw` too.

If you use 'start', the Windows console creates a new process for Windows to execute the command after start, but this mechanism does not use a given redirection for the started sub process, unfortunately.