# Why does each JDK come with 3 JREs?

Tags: java, appletviewer

I've noticed that within the `C:\Program Files\Java` folder, there's the public JRE which the JDK installed, I know this is normal. But then there's the folder `jdk1.x\jre\bin\` with `java.exe, javaw` etc in it. And then there's the compiler folder `jdk1.x\bin` which contains `javac` along with all the other files included in the JRE like `java.exe, javaw, appletviewer` etc.

Why does JDK come with all these JREs? What's the difference between these 3?

Comment: Good Question +1 for the question.

Comment: I also +1 for the question. I see no reason to install the jre with the JDK

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between java/javaw/javaws?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/whats-the-difference-between-java-javaw-javaws)

Answer (score 3):

Sun/Oracle documents the JDK directory organization here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html

> c:\jdk1.6.0\jre\bin: 
>       Executable files and DLLs for tools and libraries used by the Java platform. The executable files are identical to files in
>   /jdk1.6.0/bin.
>
> ...
>
> Note that the file structure of the JRE is identical to that of the
>   JDK's  jre directory.

Basically, the JRE directory contains the files you can redistribute with your application, should you choose to

Comment: Be careful to check the paper work about re-distribution of the jre. Last time I checked sun did not let you do this, but that was before oracle took over.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any inside knowledge, however I have found this to be useful on occasion.

Generally the JDK is not installed on peoples workstations, only the JRE.
I like to run my applications under the JRE that I know will be the same as that installed to clients.