# Unable to run HelloWorld.java from command prompt

Tags: java

I got a strange problem in my windows 7 system running jdk1.6.0_33

When I try to run a simple java program from command prompt, it opens a new window (something like java frame) and suddenly disappears. There is no result shown on command prompt also I am unable to terminate the process (using Ctrl+C) or close command prompt after this. A java process is created each time I do this. I tried to kill process using Task Manager, but that too didn't work.

I am able to run the same program using eclipse.
Here is my program

```
class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Environment variables are set as follows:

```
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin
classpath=.
```

Commands I used are,

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please provide commands which you are using to run your app

Comment: If you run java -version and javac -version on command prompt what you get?

Comment: how are you running your program from command prompt?

Comment: which command are you using to compile and run?

Comment: @Alex Stybaev Please find updated question

Comment: "Commands I used are," where you type those commands?

Comment: Run `cmd` then `cd` to folder where Hello.class is

Comment: @smith getting same result

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov javac HelloWorld.java and java HelloWorld

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov : I did the same. I used those commands from the directory where java file is located. And my classpath is set to .

Comment: @Sree What do you mean by getting same result? Are they returning you correct java and javac

Comment: @sree have u got class file after compile?

Comment: @Sree follow this link to setup java environment variables. I think your classpath is the issue. [This Link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-classpath.shtml)

Comment: @MohammodHossain Yes I got classfile created after compile

Comment: Are you getting any exception after running class file using java className

Comment: @smit javac -version returns javac 1.6.0_33 but java -version creates a new window that disappears. I set session classpath using set classpath command but that too failed.

Comment: @MohammodHossain no exceptions. As I mentioned, a new window is opened and immediately disappeared. Command prompt is not returned to new command line.

Comment: @Sree As I said earlier `java -version` supposed to return you `java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)` That means your classpath is issue. I provided link in my previous comment use that and see both commands returns proper version.

Comment: @smit Yes, it is supposed to run but its not. My classpath is set to current directory. I tried to run it using java -classpath option but that too gave same result. It was working previously but it stopped working. If it is issue with classpath, it is supposed to show some exception, right? There is no exception shown.

Comment: @Sree You current classpath shows `classpath=.`. Better you change it as provided link says. if both command returns proper `version` then you can run your `HelloWord` program. just try that once and see what happens. Nobody can help you without looking at your machine. So consider this as your last resort.

Comment: @smit I had tried that already. It could be something with my system, which I cannot figure out. As I mentioned in my question, when I give java command to run the program, cursor moves to next line and a new window (like on which appears when we do a swing program) is opened and disappears suddenly. There my command prompt stops working. It do not return to new line. I pressed Ctrl+C to stop that, but its not responding. Same time a java process is created (found it in task manager). That means my java program is running...

Comment: @Sree Try on different machine. If it works there that means something wrong with your current system. This is your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what happens if you use `java` versus `javaw` from the command prompt on Windows:

References:

- The [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) command manual page for Windows.
- [Difference between java/javaw/javaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/whats-the-difference-between-java-javaw-javaws)

Answer (score -2):

If your java class path is configured correctly.

type javac command in command prompt

You will get java compiler information.

After compile the class find your folder location if any .class file is created.

Comment: Yes he is updating his question like a lizard.