# Start osgi + JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, osgi, command-prompt, apache-felix

I have a basic example of JavaFX application into Felix framework. I start the Java App using the bat file with content

```
java -jar bin\felix.jar
```

Then the Java app is successfully started. The problem is the terminal prompt. How I can execute the command from the bar file without showing the windows prompt?

Answer (score 3):

Try starting Java with the `javaw` command instead of plain `java`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws).

Comment: I tested this: `start javaw -jar bin\felix.jar` but still the command prompt is displayed for 1 second and then hidden. How I can completely remove it?

Comment: It may be because you are starting it with a .bat file. That is, the command is displayed for running the .bat, and then hidden. Try creating a shortcut to `javaw` and tweaking the parameters wihtin (e.g. appending `"-jar bin\felix.jar"` to the command).