# Starting Background java using command prompt

Tags: java, windows, jetty, command-prompt, executable-jar

I run the jetty server using the below command, the server starts and the messages related to server start-up are displayed in command prompt:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

**What I want:**

I want to start the jetty server at the background i.e. the server should get started and no messages should be displayed in the command prompt. Hence I tried out these commands:

```
start /MIN java -jar start.jar

start /B java -jar start.jar
```

**Cons of this command:**

I am able to start the server but the java.exe window opens up displaying all the server startup messages - I don't want the java.exe window to be displayed also.

Please let me know how to start the server in such a way that:

1) The server starts at the background

2) The java.exe window does not gets displayed

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using javaw -jar start.jar

Comment: This will solve your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws

Comment: and how to display output(i.e. exception or sysout) of jar in separate text file?

Comment: One option is to configure log4j and have console appender log into flat file.

Comment: Thanks! start -javaw -jar xx.jar was the right constellation for me.

Comment: @Thomas how will you stop the services ? I need one click solution. May be bat script would be great. I have read about taskkill but it will close all javaw.exe. i would like to close only the jar process which i ran. Can anyone help me on this.