# springboot project building non-stop server on AWS EC2

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, deployment, war

I made java springboot project for the first time. SO need some advice.

I used gradle, war.

I git-pushed my project on AWS EC2.
and run `java -jar filename.war` which succeeded data communication with frontend.
But when I leave the terminal with `ctrl +c` , the java server stops.

Which way is the best to build non-stop server like `Node pm2`?

In my EC2 virtual machine, there are several projects and I use NginX to route each projects to different port numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Linux**

You can use nohup:

```
nohup java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=true your_server.war > /path/log.out &
```

Later you can use:

```
ps aux // to get the $PID of your process
kill -9 $PID // to kill the process
```

**Windows**

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562877/starting-background-java-using-command-prompt?rq=1)