# Even a simple program is not working in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I started using eclipse for the first time(earlier I always used NetBeans).

The problem is that not even a simple "hello world " program is working in it.

Path is set and everything is working from the command line but when I run any particular project in eclipse the console just shows:

**terminated theclassname [Java Applcation] c:\program files\java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\javaw.eve**

Everything is working fine from the command line, please tell me what seems to be the problem?

When I ran eclipse a couple of hours ago, everything was working fine but now it is consistently showing this problem.

**Edit:**

here is the code, as per the request in the comments:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.print("Hello!!");

    }
}
```

But the problem is not about this program, the problem is nothing is working no program is working. I just stated "a simple hello world" program as an example!

Comment: as you mentioned there is something wrong with your installation or how you have configured Eclipse

Comment: Edit and post your simple "hello world"

Comment: @PankajNimgade what do you mean by configured Eclipse, I am sorry I am using it for the first time. I just downloaded it and started. Please tell me if there are some procedures which need to be adopted for it's configuration?

Comment: @KaushalJain No, there is no special configuration needed after downloading and installing Eclipse. Additionally, when running a standalone Java application from inside Eclipse, you will always get a console output in the console view which afterwards will always show that the process is terminated (as you described). Maybe a screenshot will help showing us your problem?

Comment: How are you running the file? Do a `Project->Clean` and then Do a `Ctrl + F11->Run as Java Application`.

Comment: Its not an error its information that your program has run and  exited. Are you not getting required output?

Comment: @KaushalJain, https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

Comment: @DeepankarSingh yes I am not getting any output!

Answer (score 0):

Your ecilipse is using javax.exe to run the program. Please check in the eclipse `window-->preferences-->installed Jres-->` Check here whether the path of the JDK or JRE you have is fine or not.

If not please modify it to correct path.

Answer (score -1):

You should use java.exe (not javaw.exe) to run your program.

see:
[difference-between-java-javaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws)

you chould check your jdk settings in your Eclipse preferences.

Comment: Can you please mention in your answer exactly which setting are you talking about?