# Cannot start Eclipse Neon with JDK 9 on Ubuntu - Exit code=13

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-neon, java-9

I have **Java 9** on **64 bits**:

```
$ java -version
java version "9-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+140)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+140, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 9-ea
```

I installed **Eclipse 4.5.0** (JEE Neon) on **64 bits** under `~/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse` using the GUI (starting from eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz):

```
$ cat eclipse.ini | grep x86_64
/home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

When I run **eclipse** in the installation folder, I get a window containing the following **error**:

> ```
> JVM terminated. Exit code=13
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> -XX:+UseG1GC
> -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> -Xms256m
> -Xmx1024m
> -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
> -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
> -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
> -jar /home/user/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
> -os linux
> -ws gtk
> -arch x86_64
> -showsplash
> -launcher /home/user/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse/eclipse
> -name Eclipse
> --launcher.library /home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
> -startup /home/user/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
> --launcher.appendVmargs
> -exitdata 1b8012
> -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
> -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java
> -vmargs
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> -XX:+UseG1GC
> -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
> -Xms256m
> -Xmx1024m
> -Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
> -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
> -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
> ```

**eclipse.ini**

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
/home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

**Edit**:

- the value for `-vm` is on a different line in eclipse.ini
- changing the path value to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java` doesn't solve anything (and it doesn't seem to be a problem, because in the error message `/java` was already appended)
- changing `1.8` to `1.9` in **eclipse.ini** (before running eclipse) didn't solve the problem
- removing any of the duplicate lines (`-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`) didn't solve the problem
- being a Linux OS (Ubuntu) - there is no javaw executable
- the Eclipse installation folder path looks like this `/home/user/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse`, that dash (`-`) being the only character that could be considered "special"

My operating system is **Ubuntu 16.04**, also on **64 bits**:

```
$ uname -i
x86_64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Comment: No, I don't find it as a duplicate. Even if the exit code is the same, the cause is different (and the cause is the problem, not the effect). Also, that question uses Windows, Java 6 (32 bits), another Eclipse version ...

Comment: I see 'Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` in your JVM args twice. Also, I agree with Andy, this is a duplicate. If you look your eclipse.ini is not valid. `The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
The value must be the full absolute path to the Java executable, not just to the Java home directory.` You need to fix your eclipse.ini. This was put as a solution in the question Andy posted. Until I see that your problem persists with these fixes, then I think it should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Removing one of the following lines `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` generates exactly the same error. Adding `/java` at the end of the `-vm` value doesn't change anything. I don't find any answer in that post that answers to my question. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I don't think it's looking for the `java` executable for that `-vm` arg. I think it's looking for `javaw`

Comment: There is no `javaw`. There are only `java          javadoc       javap         javaws        
javac         javah         javapackager  javaws.real   
`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws

Comment: I think beyond this I know little more about Eclipse. I will say it looks like something is wrong with your eclipse.ini, otherwise it wouldn't be printing it back out to you when it fails. I would start minimizing things in your eclipse.ini that you don't need until you find the culprit.

Comment: @RO_engineer I flagged this as a dup because in the other question they got exit code=13 because `-vm /path/to/java` was all on one line in their eclipse.ini, and they need to be on 2 separate lines, and in your eclipse.ini it's all one 1 line.

Comment: @AndyGuibert , **eclipse.ini** has 2 different lines. That one (where `-vm` and its value are on the same line) is the **error message** that is shown in the GUI window. Also, I would like to emphasize that I am on a Linux machine (Ubuntu), not on Windows - so there is no `javaw` executable. I still see a different problem with a different possible solution, even if the error code is the same.

Comment: ah I see, I did not realize the first one was the error message. Rather than using path to the java/bin directory, you should make the -vm path go to directly to the "java" executable (since you have no javaw). In that case, I think the issue is simply that eclipse doesn't support java 9 yet.  Java 9 is still early access, and wont' officially be released until mid 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by this issues, and can be solved with the following solutions.

- You are using latest eclipse version and unsupported Java version.
- Make sure you downloaded the 64-bit version of Eclipse as well as
  64-bit version of Java software(of which you already have).
- The `-vm` option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
  The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java
  executable, not just to the Java home directory. The `-vm` option
  must occur before the `-vmargs` option, since everything after
  `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.
- You have might have special characters like #, !, @  in eclipse
  installation directory. That is, if  your eclipse installation
  address contains any special characters, then it shows that error. So
  make sure you don’t have any special characters.

If none solves,then try using `Open-JDK`