# System.out.println not printing after export from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The simplest Java program is *helloWorld*. Just one class, one main function, and one statement: **System.out.println**("hello world");

Entered that program in Eclipse Oxygen.3A as a Java project, in a package called helloWorld in a class called App, running on Java 1.8.

Runs fine in Eclipse, I can see *hello world* in Eclipse console window.
Runs fine, too, in a cmd window when started as **java helloWorld.App**.

Then - in Eclipse again - I entered a *Run Configuration* specifying the *Main class* as *helloWorld.App* and exported the project as a *Runnable JAR file* *helloWorld.jar* with *Extract required libraries into generated JAR* to some folder on the %PATH%.

In a cmd window I entered **helloWorld.jar** and expected to see *hello world* in that cmd window. But no, nothing. The program finsished correctly (I did other experiments, it does what it should) but System.out.println refuses to print in the cmd window.

What did I miss? E.g. which checkbox have I overlooked so that the exported JAR does not know what the system output is (I could not find one - but sometimes you are blind)?

Comment: What is the full command with which you execute the `jar`? Is it for example `java -jar helloWorld.jar`? Or maybe `javaw -jar helloWorld.jar`? Or just `helloWorld.jar`? Note that on most systems the default program tied to `jar` is `javaw.exe` which is `java.exe` but without command window. Thus also no sysout/syserr/sysin.

Comment: use `ftype jarfile` to list the actual command, and to change it from `javaw.exe`  to `java.exe` - like in `ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

Answer (score 2):

Run your jar like:

```
java -jar helloWorld.jar
```

and not just `helloWorld.jar`.

Comment: While this probably solves, can you also explain the issue? (default binding `javaw.exe`, difference to `java.exe`, ...)

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you Shanu Gupta.
However, it is not as convenient. Do you know how to instrument the program so it sees the cmd window as system output even when started by Win mechanisms?

You're right Zabuza: if I start with javaw -jar helloWorld.jar I have the same missing output as with just helloWorld.jar.

Comment: The explanation can be found at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws]