# Start Jar and Wait for it to Finish Before Continuing Batch Script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

In a batch file, I am trying to wait for a java program to finish before continuing. The program has a GUI interface.

So far I have tried both (with `java` and `javaw`)

```
javaw -jar program.jar
start "" /wait javaw -jar program.jar
start "" /wait /b javaw -jar program.jar
call javaw -jar program.jar /wait
```

Both continue on without waiting for the program to finish.

Comment: Unfortunately, after diving into the code for the program I was launching (not controlled by me) I found that the program starts new processes to perform the tasks and exits without waiting for those processes, which caused my script to continue before what I thought it was supposed to wait for. Thanks for the advice and clarifications on things.

Answer (score 0):

Javaw is meant to run in GUI and detaches the console.
Use java instead - and do not prefix with start or call - they will run the stuff in the background again. So your call should look like

```
java -jar program.jar
```

See also [What is the difference between 'java', 'javaw', and 'javaws'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/what-is-the-difference-between-java-javaw-and-javaws)