# Close window for logging

Tags: windows, eclipse

I am using Eclipse version 2019-03 on Windows 10. Whenever I launch it another window pops up as well. It looks this:

[image]

The window resembles the Windows terminal and logs all errors, that are occurring while using Eclipse. I can close this window, but then unfortunately Eclipse shuts down immediately as well.

How can I close this window without shutting down Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem persisted. Now I checked the `eclipse.ini` again to find a hint why a console window started with eclipse.

There I found the following lines:

```
-vm
jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin/java.exe
```

The command java.exe launches a java application with an associated console window. It disappeared when I changed it to:

```
-vm
jdk1.8.0_181/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

---

See here for an explanation:

[Difference between 'java', 'javawv, and 'javaws'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javawv-and-javaws)